# Visual Studio Code JavaScript Intellisense not working on inline objects

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm experiencing something that I hope there is a solution to it.
Visual Studio Code does not provide intellisense for dynamically added properties to objects or overwritted variables.

Could you please help me with that? Thanks!

```
var a = {};
a.myInstance = new SomeClass();
a. <-- no intellisense provided
```

If I do it like this it works

```
var a = {
  myInstance: new SomeClass()
};
a. <-- intellisense is indeed provided!
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, well for now it seems to be a bug but the IDE contains JSDoc and you can assign type info like this.

```
export default class App {
/** 
   @type {{
       loginSystem:LoginSystem, 
       quotesSystem:QuotesSystem,
       ui:UI
   }}
*/
libs = {};

/** @type {number} */
asd = null;
```